# Juvenile book (in/before 1970s) boy intercepts alien signals about the "Kyklos galaxy"

Tags: story-identification

Trying to recall a juvenile book (perhaps an in-class purchase from Scholastic book-club in the mid-late 1970s). Maybe a boy meets alien story, or at least boy picks up their transmissions. They ETs are talking about the "Kyklos galaxy" and the boy figures out they are using an old Greek term for the Milky Way (implying they've been here before).

Comment: Sounds vaguely familiar to me.  Could it have been a Danny Dunn book?

Comment: Possible as I must have read that entire series - but as hardcover library volumes. Quick search pulled up a title "Danny Dunn and the Voice from Space", but no text online. Straining less-than-reliable memory I think that book may have involved filling in a grid of "pixels" to decode radio signals into an image based message. So not sure. (Seem to be e-books for Miss Pickerell out there, but not for Danny.)

Comment: @r-evans You seem to have created two different accounts; if you [merge them](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), you'll then be able to leave *comments* on your own post rather than (non-)answers.

Comment: I grabbed the Danny Dunn book from the library. I remember reading it at one point. I'll try to skim it tonight.

Comment: I skimmed through to find messages and they don't receive a message until the very end. It's the grid of pixels that you remember, and there are no words, let alone "Kyklos". Sorry.

Comment: Appreciated, FB.